# Shell script to extract domain extension from a list of domainnames

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of URLS (including http://), where some are just domain names and some others include full path.

How could I programmatically using shell scripting, extract the extension (.com, .net...), taking in consideration that some extensions are .co.uk for example?

Comment: Are they all of the form www.domain.tld ? Or could they be www.something.domain.tld and just plain domain.tld ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but .co.uk is not a TLD. Could you be more clear as to what you're asking? Do you want to know the TLD only if the registrar allows second level registration, and otherwise the first and second level domains?

Comment: @McKay just changed it to domain extension.

Comment: I don't see why someone voted -1... a comment would be helpful

Comment: @Cy. , "Domain extension" isn't an unambiguous concept. You're going to need to be more clear as to how you want to choose whether or not to get the last two? There isn't a clear path. What about http://www.nic.uk/ what should be returned then? What about http://www.brasil.gov.br/ vs http://registro.br/

Comment: @McKay, I need to get the "what you're not able to register as a normal user" part of the domain name, like .uk in the case of nic.uk or .co.uk in the case of nic.co.uk.

Comment: http://nic.uk is not "able to be registered by a normal user" One cannot simply register "bender.uk" it doesn't work that way. That's why I asked about nic.uk What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Cy. let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2551/discussion-between-mckay-and-cy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you'd need a list of everything you're considering a "TLD"  There are a finite number of these.  Then for each URL, you'd see if anything in your list matches that URL, and if so, print it out.  The reason you need to construct the list yourself is that .co.uk is not a TLD. .uk is the TLD and .co is a subdomain.

Or you could construct an enormously long regex (for example, extracting .co.uk, .com, .ca, .biz):

```
$ perl -ne 'next unless /^http:\/\/[^ \/?]+(\.com|\.co\.uk|\.ca|\.biz)/; print $1, "\n"'
```

Answer (score 2):

The most robust way is to use a library to parse the url. For example, in Python:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
domain = urlparse('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/path/to/file.html').netloc
tld = domain.split('.')[-1]
print tld
```

will prints out just the net location (or what I think you meant TLD in this case)

UPDATE: prints the TLD this time, instead of the whole domain.

Comment: the Net location in this case is "www.mydomain.co.uk.', which is not the same as the TLD, he wants just the top level (or two).

Comment: Okay, that's better, except his answer is crazy.

Comment: As McKay pointed out, .uk is TLD, .co.uk is not. You can modify my code provide special case for .co.uk